# How do I join Windows 7 Pro machine to a 2000 server domain?

Tags: windows-7

I have tried a few suggestion with no success.  The error I receive is "An attempt to resolve the DNS name of a DC in the domain being joined has
failed. Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that
can resolve DNS names in the target domain."  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you do a nslookup fqdn?

Comment: open a command prompt do an ipconfig /all does it show valid dns servers?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are using one of the AD DNS integrated servers as the DNS server for the Win 7 machine? There shouldn't be any trickery in making this work.

Answer (score 1):

Make your that your domain's DNS servers are listed as the primary and secondary DNS settings for the Windows 7 machine.  If you only have one DNS server then don't put anything for the secondary DNS.